# Read JSON data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I Have method in my controller which returns json data.

```
public JsonResult Data()
{
    return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Now how do i read and store above returned data using jQuery? I am trying belwo

```
$("#btn").click(function () {
    $.getJSON("Controller/Data", function(result) {
           alert(result.Name + " ");
    });
});
```

**Data returned**

It returns multiple list,which has multiple items

```
eg : [0] {MyList} and then it has Name,Region etc
     [1] {MyList} and then it has Name,Region etc
```

Comment: Please also post jquery code. how you calling this method by jQuery?

Comment: What is the format of the returned JSON?

Comment: If you fetch a string in data returned you can read this data using JSON.parse

Comment: @Richa I mean, can you please post the JSON that is being returned by your `Data()` endpoint

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Edited. Hope i am clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the look of your returned JSON, you are returning an array of objects. To access these you can use the index of the object within the array. For example:

```
$.getJSON("Controller/Data", function(result) {
    console.log(result[0].Name);
});
```

Alternatively, you can loop through all the returned items:

```
$.getJSON("Controller/Data", function(result) {
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        console.log(result[i].Name);
    }
});
```

Comment: Note the `[]` indexers - this is different to the code you have in the question.

Comment: <= IE8 may not like `result[i].Name`. So, I'd prefer `result[i]['Name']`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        data: {},
        async: true,
        url: "/Controller/Data/",
        datatype: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (key, data) {
                alert(data.Name);
                alert(data.Region);
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do

```
$.getJSON("Controller/Data", function(result) {
    console.log('result');
    $.each(result, function(key,value) {
       console.log(value.name);
       // all other computations
    });
});
```